# Random in C++11 with closed interval

Tags: c++, c++11, random

The code below generate the number between `[0,PI)` as default:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main()
{
  std::random_device rd;
  std::default_random_engine re(rd());
  //std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unifPhi(0., M_PI);//[0.,PI) // <- default
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unifPhi{0.0, std::nextafter(M_PI, 2.*M_PI)};//probably [0.,PI]
  for(unsigned int i=0u;i<10u;++i)
    std::cout << unifPhi(re) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I would like  generate a number between `[0,PI]`. To be clear the second bracket must be `]`, not `)` (with closed interval).

Could somebody tell me if the code above is correct?

Comment: How do you know the difference? In a truly uniform distribution P(PI) = P(x) = 0, 0 <=x < PI.

Comment: @user515430 Because floating point numbers are not real numbers; they are discrete. The number of `float`/`double`/`long double`s in `[0,M_PI]` is finite and exactly one greater than the number in `[0, M_PI)`.

Comment: @Casey I know that. My question was more about what problem the OP is trying to solve that depends on the fact you state.

Answer (score 3):

That looks correct. Looking [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) it says the generated value will be in the range `[a, b)`. Since `a = 0` and `b` is the smallest number greater than `M_PI`, you should get a value in `[0, PI]`.